# Control in MasterPage is not declared

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, code-behind

I have a hyperlink control in my Masterpage like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkLoginButton">Login</asp:HyperLink>
```

When I reference the control in the Page Load event on the Masterpage  codebehind

```
lnkLoginButton.Text = "Go to..."
```

I get this error when building

```
error BC30451: Name 'lnkLoginButton' is not declared
```

This happens even when I drag a control into the Masterpage from the toolbox.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is this control inside any place holder that is overwrited later from the page ?

Comment: I only run this code when a user is logged in
If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
  lnkLoginButton.Text = "Go to..."
End If

Comment: a) be sure - did you call that from the page, or from the masterpage ?  b) from what HyperLink is surround ? maybe from the LoginControl ?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your master page is inheriting from the code behind class correctly.  If the namespace and class name don't match, that would explain why it can't see the Button.